# Visual studio 2005 hangs when debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

Visual studio debugger hangs while loading symbols for my application(native IA64), SP1 is installed. This started to occur, after i install debugging tools for windows(64 bit version), and reboot my computer. This issue is not depend on my project, even with new project debugger hangs.

**UPDATE:**
When i try to attach to the running process, the same situation repeats. Visual studio hangs while loading symbols(for kernell32.dll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`symsrv.dll` is responsible for loading symbols from a symbol server - you might try renaming the one installed by Debugging Tools for Windows and see if the VS debugger starts working again.

Answer (score 2):

Is it completely hanging, or just taking a long time to load the symbols?

If you using a symbol server to access debug symbols for the Windows DLLs, VS2005 can try to access the symbol server every time you debug.

The way around this is to load the symbols once, and then uncheck the symbol server URL under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols. As long as the OS libraries haven't changed since you last downloaded the symbols, there's no reason to access the remote server every time.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588857/start-debugging-takes-forever-in-visualstudio-2005/588916#588916).